# Drupal combo box

Tags: drupal

How do you create a combo box using Drupal Form API (FAPI)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there is no combobox form element you will need to use [hook_elements()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_elements/6) and a callback to create a custom combobox form element

[Check out these docs](http://drupal.org/node/37862) for an example of how to use hook_elements()

If by combobox you mean a drilldown, check out [hierarchical select](http://drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another technique for multigroup: http://drupal.org/project/flexifield

But maybe by combo box you wanted this: http://drupal.org/project/select_or_other

If neither of those do it, here is a post about more complex hierarchal options...
http://groups.drupal.org/node/23899